# Maven Profile Inheritance

Tags: maven, maven-3

is there really no possibility to inheritance profiles from a parent pom to a child pom?

I would like to declare a profile with more than 1 plugin so it's not possible to do it in the plugin management.

http://www.dashbay.com/2011/03/maven-profile-inheritance/

Comment: Why do you need the profile?

Comment: The profile is a standard execution for all projects e.g. virenscan assembly the result etc.